# Angular 6 asynchronous data loading with multiple tabs - Freezes UI

Tags: google-chrome, http, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, angular6

I have a screen with multiple tabs around 10 to 12. I am loading data in each tab component separately in OnInit. When the request is in pending state chrome network tab, the UI freezes. Not able to click the already loaded tabs. Is this the browser behavior or Angular?

I would like to understand whether asynchronous actions in browser affects the rendering performance.